# Здравствуйте. Объясните, пожалуйста, работу цикла for простым языком с практическими примерами

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Объясните, пожалуйста, работу цикла for простым языком с практическими примерами

Comment: почему мой вопрос опускают? разве я задал его неправильно?

Comment: Но это ведь нужно смотреть в книжках и в описании языка. Для SO вопрос слишком абстрактный

Comment: хорошо... получается мой вопрос следует удалить?

Comment: Да, следует удалить. Объяснение работы цикла со всеми примерами есть в любом учебнике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, у вас есть список `l = [1,3,5,7,9]` чтобы его вывести на экран по одному символу придётся писать

```
print(l[0])
print(l[1])
print(l[2]) 
print(l[3]) 
print(l[4])
```

Это слишком долго. Для этого можно использовать цикл for:

```
for i in L:
    print(i)
```

Где i будет поочерёдно принимать значения списка  L у выводить их на экран. Также можно использовать цикл for если вам нужно сделать какие-либо действия со всеми элементами списка. Можно использовать функцию range:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    sum += i
```

Вычислит сумму всех элементов от 1 до 9 (без использования списка)

Практические примеры - вычисление факториала:

```
n = int(input())
n += 1
res = 1 #результат должен быть 1, чтобы не получилось 0 * x
for i in range(1,n): #цикл начинается с 1 (чтобы не умножить на 0 и продолжается до n)
#в начале я добавил n + 1, т.к цикл как последнее значение берёт n - 1 (пока i < n - строгое неравенство)
# и чтобы цикл умножил результат на само число n - его нужно увеличить на 1    
    res *= i

print(res)
```

Вывод таблицы умножения на 6:

```
a=1
for i in range (10):
    print('6 *',a,'=',6*a)
    a=a+1
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можете рассказать, как его практически применить? у меня с этим беда... (например, вычисление факториала)

Comment: @jfkvy234 я добавил, посмотрите примеры

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!